# My really simple C program doesn't compile. Any idea?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Here's my innocent-looking program

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Sorry");
        return 0;
    }

    char key[]= "45WPbZNljDN6CUCUU6ga";
    FILE* inpFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE* outFile = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    if(!inpFile || !outFile)
    {
        printf("oops");
        return 0;
    }

    enc(inpFile,outFile,key);
    fclose(inpFile);
    fclose(outFile);
}
```

enc() is defined elsewhere but it's not a problem. When I try to compile using the VS2010 command prompt, everything goes berserk.  However, when I remove the argument-check block, it compiles fine.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char key[]= "45WPbZNljDN6CUCUU6ga";
    FILE* inpFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE* outFile = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    if(!inpFile || !outFile)
    {
        printf("oops");
        return 0;
    }

    enc(inpFile,outFile,key);
    fclose(inpFile);
    fclose(outFile);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the compiler error?

Comment: What Martin said. Also, are there includes that you're missing?

Comment: What line is the compiler complaining about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is compiled as a C program (.c extension with VS2010), it is not valid to declare variables after executable statements.  You would need to move the declarations (`key`, `inpFile`, and `outFile`) all up to the front of `main` (prior to the first `if` statement).

Comment: It is valid in the "recent" C standards, it's just that Microsoft doesn't support it (they use C89).

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft C compiler adheres to an older standard of the C language where declaration of variables must be done before any other statements (strict C89). The reason the second compiles is because the variables are declared first. I would recommend declaring your variables (without initializing) then doing the check and then finally initializing your 2 file pointers.